# What can be the dimension of the kernel of the following linear mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The linear mapping is the following:$ \varphi :{ \mathbb{R} }^{ 9 }\rightarrow { \mathbb{R} }^{ 5 }$

And what can be an example for the smallest and biggest value for the dimensions of the kernel?

So, I'm looking for a function for that $f : V → W$ any two vectors $x$ and $y$ in $V $ $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f( \alpha x)=\alpha f(x) $

I tried many functions without any success, I think maybe some kind of algebraic expression a matrix or something else could be the solution. Appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the kernel if $\varphi\equiv 0?$ What is the kernel if $\varphi(x_1,\cdots,x_9)=(x_1,\cdots,x_5)?$

Comment: For one we can make the kernel 9 dimensional by sending everything to 0. You should think about the maximal number of linearly independent elements in $\mathbb{R}^5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the maps
$$
(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) \mapsto (0,0,0,0,0)
\quad\mathrm{and }\quad
(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) \mapsto (a,b,c,d,e)\;.
$$
In general, recall that given $\varphi :{ \mathbb{R} }^{ 9 }\rightarrow { \mathbb{R} }^{ 5 }$, we have
$$
\dim\operatorname{Im}\varphi + \dim\operatorname{Ker}\varphi = \dim \mathbb{R}^9\;.
$$

Comment: So if the kernel is  φ≡0 then the kernel is 0? And in which way can I write it in an algebraic way?

Comment: The kernel of $\varphi$ is everything that maps to zero. In the first one, since *everything* maps to zero, $\dim\operatorname{Ker}$ is nine; all nine dimensions map to zero. In the second map, since there are only five dimensions available in $\Bbb{R}^5$ to map to, four of the dimensions have to map to zero.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

What can the the smallest and the biggest value for the dimension of the image? Then use the rank-nullity formula.

Answer (score 1):

The image of $\varphi$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^5$ so its dimension belongs to the set $\{0,\ldots,5\}$ and so by the rank nullity theorem $$\dim \ker\varphi=\dim \Bbb R^9-\operatorname{rank}(\varphi)=9-\operatorname{rank}(\varphi)\in\{4,5,\ldots,9\}$$